# Reuse sub-components in UML component diagram

Tags: architecture, uml, enterprise-architect, component-diagram

**IN SHORT:** Currently I perform a lot of white-box modelling in Sparx Enterprise Architect. However, I wonder that EA does not allow me to add a sub-component twice. Is it a UML modelling issue or a tool problem?

**ILLUSTRATION:** In order to explain my topic, let us assume that we are going to model an apartment. The apartment consists of rooms, namely bath and living room. Both kind of rooms comprise a door. The doors are basically equal - same manufacturer, same product.

**GOAL:** The room's doors are to be equal. Hence, we should not model them individually but reuse a single door component (from my point of view). The following graphic shows my setup:

[image]

Now, I want to create component diagram. What I want to achieve is shown below. You will guess that it was not possible for me to obtain the desired model. Instead there is an issue with the red component.

[image]

**ISSUE:** For component diagrams I always choose to insert the component as a link in Sparx Enterprise Architect. As soon as I try to paste the door (sub-)component a second time I receive the following feedback:

[image]

**NOTES:** From my experience I know that an error message from Sparx Enterprise Architect usually indicates some modelling error. I read a lot on the internet and even bought a UML book which is exhaustive on the topic. Unfortunately, in neither of these sources I was able to find a solution for my modelling problem. The only ways to work around this issue would be to insert the door component as an instance instead of a link into the component diagram or to deep copy the door component. However, both options feel unnatural and I feel that they would cause subsequent problems during the further modelling process.

Comment: You are visibly in front of EA limitation, but in a way this is a chance because the diagram you try to do is wrong, it says Door is a the a sub component of Bath Room and Living Room and this is false. Out of that why are you using components ? The 'natural' way is to use classes (*Apartment* ...) and an object diagram

Comment: @bruno I don’t think it is wrong. This is a typical use of a bill of material in industry, where you assemble standard components to make more complex parts (which themselves can be reused in different products). Reuse is what components are meant for: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering

Comment: @Christophe there is a big difference between to use an existing component and to define a component as a sub-component. To use a component means in fact a component instance being an actual entity if I can say

Comment: @bruno you have a point here.  However, can't you represent either the **packaged elements** (in which case you'll be right since the Door would only be packaged in one component) as well as the **internal parts** in a component diagram? i.e. isn't fig.11.47 page 212 in the UML 2.5.1 specs a component diagram ?  (in which case indeed, the  embedded components should be represented as parts,  with a ":" in front of component name, which is not done here)

Comment: Maybe try with a composite structure diagram to show the parts of a component. Apparently you use the packaging component, which has the semantic that bruno mentions.  The answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50491759/3723423) provides an interesting hint.

Comment: @Christophe the ':' indicates this is not component but component instance,. Referring to structured classifier (a component is one of them) `:xx` is in fact a *part*, a property specifying instances that the structured classifier (here component) owns by composition

Comment: @Christophe: Of course I could use a composite structure diagram (actually I did it in my real project). I would then need to handle Bath and Living Room as black-boxes within apartment, but I want to produce a white-box model.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for taking the time to discuss my problem :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diagram you are showing is the notation for *packaged* Elements. Packaging has no semantics. You can move your elements wherever you want in the model browser and in the diagram. It only helps you, to keep the model nicely ordered. For this purpose it makes sense, that each element can be contained in only one packaging element. Therefore, it was not possible to do show the door in both rooms.

From what I understood, you want to model, that both the Bathroom and the Living Room have a part, that is of type door. For this purpose UML uses a composite structure diagram. It allows to show the internal structure of both components and classes.
[image: component House]
In this example, the composite structure diagram is shown in a compartment of the House component, which is shown in component diagram. As you see, the sub components of the House can also show their internal parts. This works for any level of nesting. Of course, if the diagram becomes too big, you can also use dedicated composite structure diagrams, that only show the internal structure of one component.

Now, some people call everything with a colon an "instance". In a way, they are right. The semantics of *every* structure diagram is that it tells us what allowed instances are - and that actually does not depend on the colon. Only here the diagrams tells us something about instances being a part of some other instance: Two instances of Door being a part of one instance of Bathroom and Living Room, who in turn are part of one instance of House. The modeler chose not to show, of what type of instance the House is a part. It could be a City, and the City could be part of a State, and the State could be part of a Country and so on. It really depends on the focus of the diagram (and the purpose of the model). The shown diagram only says something about *all* instances of the House, no matter what it is a part of. Therefore, there is no colon on the top level.

I didn't model this with Enterprise Architect. However, since this notation is firmly within the bounds of the UML specification, it should be possible.

I assume you are talking about software components. If you are talking about physical rooms, you should consider using SysML, which offers more possibilities to model the internal structure of things.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I edited my answer to explain that.

Answer (score 3):

You can not add the same element twice on a diagram. For elements being connected you can use "Virtualize connector end" from the connector context. That will create a shadow of the element on the diagram. However, I would not recommend using that since it creates a bunch of different issues.

The UML spec itself does not forbid to have elements more than once on a diagram. But they use that only on *very* few diagrams where generalization is used and it is obvious that actually the element is the same. Now that is exactly the problem when you re-use an element on a diagram. There is no way to determine whether you have two different elements which look identically or whether they are just two renderings of the same thing. For that reason it is my recommendation to be clear and use elements only once on a diagram.

As an alternative consider using composite diagrams being shown inside the two Room components. You can make either composite, place the shared sub-component in that diagram and make the composite diagram show inside the main component. This can be done by dragging the composite diagram inside the components and make them fit:

[image]

Embedding a diagram in Enterprise Architect can be achieved as follows:

1. *Right-click component -> Select Composite Diagram* allows you to select an already existing diagram. It will be opened as soon as you double-click the component.
2. *Right-click component -> Show Composite Diagram in Frame* or *Right-click component -> Show Composite Diagram in Compartement* will embed the diagram directly into the outer component view.

[image: Options for embedding composite diagrams]

Comment: I just notice you are using instances inside. In that case you need to create two instances since an instance represents exactly one real thing. You cant have the SAME door inside two rooms. If it connects the rooms it's something like a separate instance, but not inside both rooms.